# php simple specific ksort

Tags: php, reverse, sorting

I would like to sort an array like:

```
$k = array (
    "2135p" => "toto",
    "2137l" => "tosdgsto",
    "2135p^2211i" => "sdf",
    "2135p^2211i^2224o" => "sdf",
    "2137l^2365c" => "sdff"
);
```

with this order -> `"2137l", "2137l^2365c", "2135p", "2135p^2211i", "2135p^2211i^2224o"`

krsort doesn't do it

It's for displaying inset comments ids

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need to implement your own `uksort()` implementation to get what you need.

Comment: ok then it there a way to easily compare explode("^", "2137^2365^....") and  explode("^", "2137^...")

Comment: Yes I wouldn't explode if you are trying to sort them from lowest to highest, simply `str_replace('^', '', $key);` to make one long number.

Comment: I'm sorry your answer was working with plain numbers, actually I can have letters also, the replace thing doesn't work

Comment: You still may be able to do a < or > string comparison depending on how you want your letters to sort relative to the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `krsort()` the `SORT_NUMERIC` flag and it should work.

Alternately use the `uksort()` function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php and define your own comparator.

Comment: I see the problem. You need to sort the sub-numbers too right? You can sort of fix it by running `ksort()` first, then running `krsort()` with SORT_NUMERIC. (i.e. sort twice). But for a proper fix you'll have to use `uksort()` and split up the string yourself.